# Right way to use Streams to tokenize a string containing delimited host IPs and port numbers

Tags: java, java-stream

I am new to Java and writing code to parse and validate the ZooKeeper hosts and ports passed from the command line. The input to the function will be something like `"127.0.0.1:2181,192.168.23.10:2181"`.

I am experimenting with the Java Stream API and want to know if the code below is any good or should I simply split the string on `","`, iterate each and then split based on `":"` before validating the inputs?

The following code seems pretty awkward. Any suggestions to improve the code are welcome.

```
  private boolean validateZookeeperServers(String servers) {

    class HostPort {
      private String host;
      private String port;

      public HostPort(String host, String port) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
      }

      public boolean isValidHost() {
        return true;
      }

      public boolean isValidPort() {
        return Integer.parseInt(port) > 1024 &&  Integer.parseInt(port) < 32000;
      }
    }

    List<HostPort> hostPortList = Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(servers)
      .map(str -> { 
         String[] hp = str.split(":"); return new HostPort(hp[0], hp[1]);
        })
      .collect(toList());

    return hostPortList.stream().allMatch(t -> t.isValidHost() && t.isValidPort() );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks William Price. I realized using InetSocketAddress instead of HostPort is a better.

Answer (score 1):

As you had mentioned in your comment, you could try with `InetScoketAddress` instead of this HostPort class.

For your current approach, It can be improved slightly as shown here,

```
Predicate<HostPort> isValidPort = HostPort::isValidPort;
Predicate<HostPort> isValidHost = HostPort::isValidHost;

return Stream.of(servers.split(","))
                        .map(s -> s.split(":"))
                        .map(hpa -> new HostPort(hpa[0],hpa[1]))
                        .allMatch(isValidHost.and(isValidPort));
```

Comment: Technically, `Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(servers)` is better than `Stream.of(servers.split(","))`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way. It's a little simpler than yours:

```
List<HostPort> hostPortList = Stream.of(servers.split(","))
                .map(s -> new HostPort(s.split(":")[0], s.split(":")[1]))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Technically, `Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(servers)` is better than `Stream.of(servers.split(","))`

Comment: @Andreas, can you explain why?

Comment: @Andreas In this case using a `Pattern` will probably use more overhead, because `.split(",")` takes advantage of an optimization for single-character patterns.

Comment: @4castle Perhaps, but streaming the tokens one at a time eliminates the need for array, and if text is huge (not the case here), it doesn't have to keep all the tokens in memory at the same time. Basically the DOM vs SAX argument. I just wanted to point out the alternative, which is actually what was used in the question, so I was wondering why both answers changed it.